IFS has mismatched range sizes. Expected row count: 50500. column count: 1. Actual row count: 50499, column count: 1
I am new here and a bit of a rookie. I have the following formula which providing the error in the header.
=arrayformula(ifs(ROW(A:A)=1,"Total Before OT",A:A="","",TRUE,H2:H+J2:J+K2:K+L2:L))

The first part is to provide a title to the column and show blank if there is no data in the row.
I am just trying to sum four columns in an array.
I am using a form to collect data so array works well as the form submissions come in.
